# Array to list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, javascript-objects

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  let list = null;
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  }
  return list;
}

// output
console.log(arrayToList([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]));
// → {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}
```

since `array.value = array[i]` and in the loop the condition is set to start from `array.length -1` which is the last index of the array, so I was thinking why the output is not inverted? my understanding is list should start at `50` and decrements from there until reached `10`.
Can anyone help why the condition of the loop is set this way and not `(i = 0; i < array.length -1; i++)`. Thank you.

Comment: That list implementation doesn't really make any sense. Typically nodes have a pointer (or reference in this case) to the *next* element, and how you have this it will have circular references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code snippet does is for each value in your array, it will take it and change `list` to be

```js
list = {value: *, rest: null}
```

It then repeats the process again, but then comes to the same instruction.
In your code, the value `rest` is set to be `list` inside of itself.
So it then takes the next value and changes `rest` inside of `list` to be

```js
{value: *, rest: null}
```

So `list`'s value turns into:

```
list = {value: *, rest: {value: *, rest: null}
```

The fix is using a separate array:

```
const ArrayToList = (Array) => {
    List = {Value: null, Rest: RestArray};
    RestArray = [];
    
    // Set the first value:
    List.Value = Array[0]
    
    // Loop through the rest:
    for (let i = 1; i < (Array.length - 1); i++) {
        RestArray[i] = Array[i]
    }

    return List
}
```

Comment: Thank you this clear but just one question. I thought `something[i]` could only be done if that `something[i]` is in the for loop condition. How could you do `RestArray[i]`?

Answer (score 2):

The first time around the loop it creates an object:

```
{
  "value": 50,
  "rest": null
}
```

The second time around the loop, it puts that **inside** the new object it creates.

And so on.

Hence, `"value": 50` is the **innermost** value.